# Add field link in a Drupal 8 block form

Tags: drupal-8

I would like to had a field `link` in a custom block. Here is my code to do that :

```
public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
{

    $form['key_1'] = [
        '#title' => $this->t('Key 1 label'),
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#default_value' => '',
        '#required' => false,
    ];

    $form['key_2'] = [
        '#title' => $this->t('key 2 link'),
        '#type' => 'link',
    ];

    return $form;
}
```

Now, when I go in admin/structure/block/manage/myblock, I can see my `key 1` field. The `key 2` is not render. If I change the type for any other (textfield, textarea, file_managed) my field is properly render.
The default link module is enabled.

Is the link field type only usable in node form ?
I can understand why.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the [**Link**](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Link.php/class/Link/8.2.x) class. You need to specify the `#url` property:

```
$form['key_2'] = [
  '#title' => $this->t('key 2 link'),
  '#type' => 'link',
  '#url' => \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('some.route.name'),
];
```

Comment: It renders directly a link not a link widget form.

Comment: Then instead use `'#type' => 'url'`

Comment: I have just tried in drupal 9 and it doesn't work
 `$form['link_cta'] = ['#type' => 'link','#title' => $this->t('Button Link'),'#url' => null,'#options' => ['external' => TRUE]];`

Answer (score 0):

**To add link in block form:**

```
$form['resource_fieldset']['design_tool_link'] = [
  '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
  '#target_type' => 'node',
  '#title' => $this->t('Design Tool Link'),
  '#description' => $this->t('Select Design Tool Link'),
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#element_validate' => [
    [
      'Drupal\link\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\LinkWidget',
      'validateUriElement',
    ],
  ],
  '#attributes' => [
    'data-autocomplete-first-character-blacklist' => '/#?',
  ],
  '#process_default_value' => FALSE,
  '#default_value' => $design_tool_link ?? : '',
];

 $form['resource_fieldset']['title'] = [
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => $this->t('Title'),
];
```

**Note:** You need to use the type `'#type' => 'entity_autocomplete'`, instead of using the URL and the link type, to make it work like the Core Link widget's field.

**Also, you need to add other attributes mentioned in the code:**
Support both internal and external URLs, as well as the Core Link widget's field validation also applied.

**Can follow this reference for more info:**
https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/blob/8.8.0/core/modules/link/src/Plugin/Field/FieldWidget/LinkWidget.php#L186-203